# pylint division by zero warning

Tags: python, pylint, divide-by-zero

Is there any way to enable *division by zero warning* in pylint?

```
"""
Oh my ...
"""
SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL = 0
NUMER = 7 / SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL
```

An equivalent example in cpp issues a proper warning:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#define SOME_WRONG_MACRO 0
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int NUMBER = 7/SOME_WRONG_MACRO;
    return 0;
}
$ g++ main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:4:19: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
     int NUMBER = 7/SOME_WRONG_MACRO;
```

**EDIT**
Even if I add `const`-ness with:

```
from typing import Final
SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL: Final[int] = 0
```

I still don't get *any* warning with `pylint` (and neither with `mypy`)

Comment: The C++ compiler can do this easily because the value is constant - i.e., it's always going to be zero. In Python however, it's a variable which makes it unreasonable (if not impossible) to determine if a division by zero will occur at any given point in the code (although in your example it *could*)

Comment: `mypy` may be a better candidate for this...

Comment: Testing just now, `mypy` doesn't currently detect this (version 0.930); however, it may still be a better starting point than pylint, since it already does various tracing of values through the program

Comment: BTW, another reason why the C++ compiler can do this is that it'll often pre-calculate expressions that only involve constants at compile-time, as an optimisation, so it'll try to evaluate `7/0` as part of compilation, rather than leaving it to run-time; in other cases, it'll replace a division by a constant 2 or 4 etc by a faster "bit shift" instruction, which again alerts it to an invalid division by zero

Comment: @JiříBaum thanks, I tested it too an edited the question accordingly. A bit disappointing it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? A linter like pylint (or even a type checker like mypy) has only an extremely narrow view of your program - this isn't comparable at all to what a C++ compiler has available. It would at most only be able to "catch" cases in which you explicitly tell it that you are making this error (such as using a final literal), which is usually not sensible to warn against.

Comment: Note that this also depends on your C/C++ compiler; according to the C standard, at least, division by zero is either allowed (with Appendix F) or undefined behaviour (no Appendix F)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - mypy will often warn you that you need to check whether a variable is `None`, with some smarts in recognising whether or not you've checked for it; no reason it couldn't do similar tracing for 0, it just doesn't

Comment: (Sorry; that should be "Annex F" rather than "Appendix F" a couple of comments up)

Comment: @JiříBaum ``None`` is backed by a separate type, whereas ``0`` isn't. In most cases, ``0`` just isn't explicitly expressed but just part of an ``int`` or even more general number type – checking for its misuse would seem to be rather arbitrary compared to the many other things one can misuse.

Comment: Indeed, it would be a rather arbitrary use case as far as type-checking is concerned

Comment: The underlying AST representation of astroid used by pylint is powerful and can infer values of variable. 

```
>>> from astroid import parse
>>> parse("""
... SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL = 0
... NUMER = 7 / SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL
... """)
>>> list(a.locals["NUMER"][0].infer())
[Uninferable]
>>>list(a.locals["SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL"][0].infer())[0].value
2
```

If we change the value of ``SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL`` to 2, it could tell that the value is 3.5. So it's not impossible but would require a new check in pylint and maybe a more explicit return than Uninferable from astroid.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas can you post as an answer? it's closest so far

Comment: Linting isn't error checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying AST representation of astroid used by pylint is powerful and can infer values of variable.

```py
>>> from astroid import parse
>>> a = parse("""
 ... SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL = 0
 ... NUMER = 7 / SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL
 ... """)
>>> list(a.locals["NUMER"][0].infer())
[Uninferable]
>>>list(a.locals["SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL"][0].infer())[0].value
0
```

If we change the value of `SOME_WRONG_GLOBAL` to 2, it could tell that the value of `list(a.locals["NUMER"][0].infer())[0].value` is `3.5`.

So it's not impossible but would require a new check in pylint and maybe a more explicit return than `Uninferable` from astroid. Something being `Uninferable` does not mean that there's an error in the code, only that astroid cannot tell what the value is.